# How to localize the label of a file_field in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, filefield

I want to localize a form in my app so that all the labels are in Finnish. This is easy with all other form components, but how do I do this with a file field? It always seems to give me a label "choose file" in the button and "no file chosen" immediately after the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This dumb file field depends only on your system locale. You cannot change way it looks or behaves, which annoys many of us, not to mention the fact that it can look completely different across different platforms.

To fight the problem you have options:

1. use a flash solution like
   SWFUpload, etc.
2. use a Javascript + CSS
   solution (there are many of them,
   e.g. [this one](http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2007/09/10/styling_file_inputs_with_css_and_the_dom))

Comment: Hmph, annoying. Anyway, thanks for the clarification, I'll look into the javascript thingy.