# Rails 4: how to apply custom CSS to Rails form file field

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, filefield

I have a Rails 4 app, that uses Rails' default form (I am **NOT** using Simple Form).

One of my forms allows users to upload an image (thanks to Paperclip):

```
<td>
  <%= f.file_field :image, value: "Choose a file" %>
</td>
```

I would like to style the "choose a file button" with custom CSS.

I tried to apply an `id` to my td, as follows:

```
<td id="upload_image">
  <%= f.file_field :image, value: "Choose a file" %>
</td>
```

and then I tried to style it with the following CSS code:

```
#upload_image input {
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    background-image: none;
    border: none;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
```

But this resulted in styling the `td` itself:

[image]

And I still get this ugly button with the default style.

—————

**UPDATE**: if styling the button itself is not possible, I would like to at least put the "no file chosen" label ("aucun fichier choisi" in French) under the button, since at the moment it is taking a lot of horizontal room on my page).

Is that even possible?

—————

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
<%= f.file_field :source, :class => "ui pink button" %>
```

As does:

```
<%= f.file_field :source, class: "ui purple button" %>
```

You can apply styling this way. But again this, the clickable part is still going to be the default grey and say "Choose File". Aside from that, keep in mind the HTML file field is one of the least customizable up to you how much effort you want to expend trying to.

Comment: A better answer would be how to fully customize the upload button with own css styles.

Comment: ^^ I interpreted the question to mean how to apply custom style to the field using the helper, not what specific css to use.

Answer (score 8):

This is my solution: just wrap a form field in a label and hide it. 
No javascript.

```
<label class="btn btn-default btn-change-avatar">
    Upload new image
    <span style="display:none;">
      <%= form.file_field :avatar, id: "fileUploader"%>
    </span>
  </label>
```

Comment: very nice! I tried this example and it worked well for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

why not had a div next to the file input.... and some basic javascript

example:

```
<td id="upload_image">
  <%= f.file_field :image, value: "Choose a file" %>
  <div>Aucun fichier choisi</div>
</td>
```

javascript would be as follow (using jQuery):

```
$("#upload_image").on("change", "input", function(){
  if $(this).val() == ''
    $(this).closest("td").find("div").slideDown();
  else
    $(this).closest("td").find("div").slideUp(); 
});
```

There might be a few tweaks to do but that should get you started.

Bonne chance!

Comment: Hum, the problem is "Aucun fichier choisi" is not even an html output: it is automatically generated by the Rails form helper for the file field. I am not sure how/where I can edit this, actually.

Comment: Please view the SO entry here, seems like it cannot be changed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317049/how-to-localize-the-label-of-a-file-field-in-rails

Comment: Pretty frustrating. But thanks a lot for your time and your help.

Answer (score 0):

Upload Photo button with Remove button:

```
.d-flex.flex-row
  - if @user.image.attached?
    = link_to image_tag(@user.image.variant(resize_to_limit: [100, 100])), rails_blob_path(@user.image, disposition: 'attachment'), alt: 'user'
  - else
    = image_tag 'profile.png'
  .ms-4
    .d-flex.flex-row
      label.btn.btn-primary
        | Upload Photo
        = image_tag 'Icon-Color.svg', alt: 'icon', class: 'ps-3'
        .d-none
          = f.file_field :image
      .ps-3
        - if @user.image.attached?
          = link_to registration_path({ user: { id: @user.id }, purge: true }), method: :put, local: true, class: 'btn btn-primary' do
            = image_tag 'Trash.svg', alt: 'icon'
    .mt-1.small Up to 1 MB (300x300 px)
```

Result:

[image]